# Monitor multiple Turtlebots with 1 workstation?

Tags: linux, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This might not necessarily be ROS/Turtlebot question and instead general linux question, but is there a way to monitor multiple Turtlebots from a single workstation ROS machine using turtlebot_dashboard?

Looking at [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials/Networking%20Setup#preview), environmental variable is in use and it can contain only 1 host's name/address. It would be nicer to be able to observe dashboard of multiple bots on a single computer.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10878/monitor-multiple-turtlebots-with-1-workstation?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-08-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-08-11**:
That tutorial is written for the on robot case, you can set your ROS_MASTER_URI in a new terminal session for each robot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Open a new terminal
2. Export a new ROS_MASTER_URI for another turtlebot in that terminal
3. Run the dashboard
4. Tada! you have two dashboards running connected to multiple turtlebots :)

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2